# Accessing Swift enum property from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums, swift2

Below is how I declared `enum` in Swift. I have a property of this `enum` type in one class. But I am not able to access this property from Objective-C. Is there any workaround for this? I wrote my app completely on Swift. I am now integrating the thirdparty SDK which is completely on Objective-C. I need the value of this `enum` property in Objective-C.

```
 @objc public enum PaymentType: NSInteger {
    case COD
    case NB
    case CARDS
    case PAYTM
    case CITRUS
}
    var modeOfPayment: PaymentType?
```

When I'm trying to access this property in Objective-C, it says

> property modeOfPayment not found

```
NSLog(@"%d",[Helper sharedInstance].order.modeOfPayment);
```

Comment: May be problem is caused by optionals? In objc enums can't be optional.

Comment: Show the complete declaration of the property; that code fragment is not enough to see potential issues.

Comment: Enums are supposed to be non-optional because they have an unchangeable number of cases. You could add a NONE case for a `nil` equivalent. Optional types are not exposed to ObjC.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: u r right. I have set a default value then it became accessible:         var modeOfPayment: PaymentType = PaymentType.COD;

Answer (score 1):

```
@objc public enum PaymentType: Int {
    case none
    case COD
    case NB
    case CARDS
    case PAYTM
    case CITRUS
}
    var modeOfPayment: PaymentType = .none
```

Make sure that you have case none in the Swift enum and assigned `.none` to property